We have a bad case of socks on ELL, please help. UPDATE #4
I suspect there are at least eight sock-puppets operating on ELL. I've downvoted, I've flagged, I've commented but to no avail. After 18 hours of abuse, their accounts are still working, and "earning" as much as 300 rep at a time.
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360073/1694
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360071/1694
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360078/1694
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360069/1694
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360070/1694
UPDATE
Three accounts have had their reputation reduced to 1
One more to go with 74 rep
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360045/1694
Thank you to those who raised multiple red flags.
2nd UPDATE
Four accounts have been suspended exactly one year for voting irregularities.
I don't know if there were eight sock puppets but I think there may be a fifth or a sixth one lurking somewhere, because one of the suspended accounts managed to earn the 100 association bonus. How on earth is that possible?



UPDATE 11 December
The user Asim Ahmed (I no longer care about naming and shaming) has several active accounts on a few SE sites such as Physics, Mathematics, EL&U and Meta. Their accounts can post questions and automatically earn 15 rep whenever they accept their sockpuppet's answer. The user probably has other accounts, active, with different usernames. Maybe the username Asim Ahmed is a way to distract attention from their other, more anonymous-sounding, accounts.

Asim Ahmed's sockpuppets, user:621056, and  user:611858, are currently active on ELU. See their recently deleted answer on EL&U.
Asim continues to proliferate. Perhaps it's time to delete their accounts?
December 14, 2024

Interesting news, the suspensions of user:258253, and user:146770, alias Asim Ahmed,  will be lifted on 1st January 2025

There must be some “clerical” or bug in the system. There simply has to be. Or maybe initially the two accounts were suspended for only a month, but when the problem got worse each of their socks were suspended for a year.
I would hope the two accounts, mentioned above, will have their suspensions extended immediately.

Questions

Why are the 17 accounts (AFAIK) not deleted?
Why are they not simply banned across the network? Is it too late? Is the procedure too messy?

As of Dec 14, 2024 …



user number
username
member for
account status




user:261535
Asim Ahmed
5 days
ACTIVE


user:261345
Asim Ahmed
5 days
SUSPENDED Dec 10, 2025 at 12:07


user:261370
Asim Ahmed
5 days
SUSPENDED Dec 10, 2025 at 13:29


user:261399
Asim Ahmed
5 days
SUSPENDED Dec 10, 2025 at 13:51


user:261382
Asim Ahmed
5 days
SUSPENDED Dec 10, 2025 at 13:52


user:260796
Asim Ahmed
6 days
SUSPENDED Dec 09, 2025 at 11:35


user:260791
Asim Ahmed
6 days
SUSPENDED Dec 09, 2025 at 12:07.


user:260278
Asim Ahmed S
8 days
ACTIVE


user:260266
Asim Ahmed
8 days
SUSPENDED Dec 09, 2025 at 11:33


user:260266
Idiot
8 days
SUSPENDED Dec 09, 2025 at 11:33


user:259996
Asim Ahmed
9 days
SUSPENDED Dec 09, 2025 at 11:36


user:259964
Asim Ahmed
9 days
SUSPENDED Dec 06, 2025 at 20:37


user:258692
Asim Ahmed
12 days
ACTIVE


user:258653
Idiot Race
12 days
SUSPENDED Dec 6, 2025 at 11:53


user:258688
Aim Ahmed
12 days
SUSPENDED Dec 6, 2025 at 20:46


user:258253
Asim Ahmed
13 days
SUSPENDED Jan 1, 2025 at 17:43


user:257870
Asim Ahmed
14 days
SUSPENDED Dec 6, 2025 at 13:11


user:187977
user93793
7 months
SUSPENDED  Dec 6, 2025 at 11:57


user:146770
Asim Ahmed
3 years, 1 month
SUSPENDED Jan 1, 2025 at 17:43



If ever there was an argument for banning multiple accounts–because they're not against regulations–this is it.

Reduced to 1 due to the -100 rep for red flags

@ShadowWizard  Ahh! I forgot about the number of red flags. Good news!

Just one sock left with 74 rep user:258290

Well moderators can and should handle this manually by deleting all the accounts associated with this voting ring. I custom flagged one post, but as it's weekend it might take few days. If you see more posts from those socks, you can also report in the Tavern chat, and to Smoke Detector.

I have flagged all of them I think. Flagged to moderators for:  deletion.

@ShadowWizard see my update. Meta seems to get things done more quickly than on ELL. Effectively we have just one active mod, two have been MIA for some time, and one keeps a very low profile.

@Mari-LouA for emergency cases I agree that CM should be involved faster, and they do monitor MSE more, not to mention mods there are much more active and can call CM who is on emergency duty in a very short while. However, that's not the case here. It's very severe, sure, but unless the abuser actually cause a big damage to the site, I don't think it's considered emergency. As long as it's handled in 1-2 days locally by site mods, it's fine.

@ShadowWizard   One or two days. I first talked about this on December 6th. I observed that the user was not suspended across the network on December 8th. In the meantime, let's wait some more. OK. I raised one red flag on Asim's deleted answer on EL&U, hopefully it will be seen later today and the user will be suspended on EL&U, as well.

Yesterday I was busy all day but Asim was even busier:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/360250/1694; https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/360246; https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/360242/1694; https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/360233/1694; https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/360240/1694. The flagging system works but as long as their accounts are not banned across the network, they will continue to disrupt this site.

It took less than a day for a local mod here to handle it. The mod couldn't know the user will do that again on other sites. You can also custom flag and/or post on Physics meta about the new activity of the socks, and I believe it will be handled there as well. If you want to involve a CM yourself, you can e.g. post in this chat room giving proof of the cross site bad behavior, ping JNat and they'll handle it at some point. (Though likely more than 1-2 days)

@ShadowWizard    It took less than a day after I posted on Meta. Coincidence? Maybe. But the user's posts, all 17 of them, (or less I can't remember the exact number) were visible on the main page, on a Friday, for about 18 hours until their accounts were suspended and their posts deleted. P.S I am not a user on Physics. I've averted the mods here and on EL&U, isn't that enough?

@Mari-LouA It's worth noting that mods can only suspend on their own site(s), so network suspensions are always issued by CMs. As for the delay in handling the posts on ELL before this Meta post, I couldn't anticipate it becoming this much of a problem beforehand, and was busy with stuff off-site before I was able to handle the rest. (Also, you may be interested in my short update in my answer below.)

@Laurel you've done more than enough,I'm fully and painfully aware that you are working alone on ELL.

Hello! I am kind of an active user over chem.SE (not so much now) and such type of activities has been plaguing the site with the user leaving troll comments, making unnecessary edits and leaving post URL in the comment section. The account were destroyed within minutes but then new accounts were created and then leaving threatening comments to me. A mod over there contacted the CM and they said they have done what needs to be done. The problem persisted even after that and the mod also said they have done their part and nothing else could be done.

More details in my posts: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/targeted-troll-comments ... https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/edits-by-anonymous-user-and-approved-by-community-bot ... https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5399/whats-the-point-of-users-commenting-the-url-of-the-question-itself-in-the-comme

@NilayGhosh are you saying the  user on Chemistry and ELL are the same person? When I checked Asim and their sock puppets' network profiles I don't recall seeing that site listed. But Physics, and Mathematics were always present.

No, no. They are not the same person (at least I don't see any link). But such problems and instances happened in chem.SE as well.

And I just now realized that the user in Ch.SE (Name: Satyajit Mandal) has now started his activity in a bountied question (leaving unnecessary comments and pinging users who left a comment). He does not come often but when a bounty starts, he rise from his slumber and starts his corruption.

But in order to post comments the user needs to have at least 50 rep, creating new accounts would not allow them to comment on posts other than their own question(s). Did you look at their profile pages and see how they (the account "holders") earned their rep? Obviously, this user is abusing the system, and should be suspended for at least a year. Just keep flagging, and encourage other community members to flag until this user loses 100 rep = six red flags.

I don't know how they are earning reps or able to comment but the mods there acknowledged that there is a glaring loophole in the system which they are unable to track and close. I pushed them a little but unfortunately there is no updates from them. You can see the details in the posts. For now, I have been flagging the comments (right now, there are 5-6 flags to review) but this is frustrating (this has been going on for 4-5 months with no solution whatsoever).

@NilayGhosh  If you look at their profile page(s) you can see where their reputation points came from . You could probably figure out from the upvotes if they came from trusted users or from new accounts. New accounts = sock puppets. And, again, I encourage you to ask your community members to flag  this misbehaviour. Consider bringing this up in the Tavern, the Meta chat group.  There are users who can better advise.

They are stuck at 1 reputation. Almost all the profiles gets destroyed within minutes. Currently, few users are aware of this as well as the mods through flags and meta posts.

I feel sorry for anyone else who shows up in the next few months whose name is also Asim Ahmed...

@DanGetz Me too. Hopefully, the chances of that occurring with a brand new user, are slim.

@Lambie good news. Only four accounts are still standing. Three have been banned across the network. while I think one slipped through the net because its account is not listed. The other 16 accounts are deleted, so no January pardon is expected :)

@Mari-LouA I just don't understand. I see they have been suspended for a time but not thrown  out. Is that incorrect?

@lambie, if you search for Asim Ahmed in the user page, you'll only find four accounts. https://ell.stackexchange.com/users Count the number of sockets in the table I made, there are 19, which means 15 accounts have been deleted.

Yes, luv but why suspended (temporary suspension network wide)  and not kicked off the site?

Right, so you're saying why didn't all of the accounts get deleted, while I'm saying progress has been made.And I thought you didn't realize that 15 accounts had been removed.  @Lambie when you leave comments, it's sometimes hard to know your thought process, you may think your observations are obvious but it's not always like that.

@Mari-LouA I feel the same about your comments. Yes, I mean that since  the powers that be see that some person has that many sockpuppet accounts, why only just suspend them? Yes, I see the 15 were "suspended"  but not removed. That's my complaint. Nopt to YOU but to THEM.

@Lambie   No, the 15 accounts have been removed. Try searching for them, they're gone. Kaput. Last time I looked, one day ago, there were only four left.

@Lambie  To be clear, since 18/19 December, 15-17  accounts no longer exist. They have been deleted by SE staff. To make it easy, click on the first links in my post, the authors' names  (Asim Ahmed, Idiot Race etc.)  no longer appear. I was hoping Laurel would update their answer, so I could accept it, but she hasn't, not yet in anycase.

One of the socks has changed username: danger problem https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/266167/danger-problem

I think I've handled everything here that needs to be handled. (I left one or two questions up which were answered by well meaning people.) Of course, you can flag to let me know if I've missed something.
As you may be able to see, I've been using "rude or abusive" flags here. This flag (along with "spam") is unique in that it allows users of modest rep to help delete posts. You can use this flag if you're absolutely, positively certain it's another related sock and it's not a question that's attracted real answers (even though this isn't the normal way of handling this–I'm making an exception), or the post content itself is abusive, like keyboard mashing (a normal use of such flags).
You can also bring the problem to Charcoal HQ chat, to get the attention of other potential flaggers.

I've been communicating with mods on other sites as this has spread, and was even able to get CMs involved, which will hopefully be the final word on this.

Please explain to me why this person is simply not "User Removed" material?

@Lambie It's a matter of preference: Some of the mod tooling is easier to use when the accounts aren't deleted. Behind the scenes, destroying the account also causes a year suspension while deleting the posts, so the end result is not dramatically different from the perspective of any non-mod.

Well, I'd like to have the satisfaction knowing the person has been removed.

Why wasn't user93793 banned across the network? They have several accounts with the 100 association bonus, in a week or a month's time (if they can wait that long) they could replicate their shenanigans

Finally, how did one of the accounts earn 300 rep? I can't find my comment expressing my shock but I think it was user93793.

I don't have the authority or power to suspend users across the network, if I did I wouldn't be bothering you. I asked Glorfindel, a moderator on six sites including Meta, to intervene but they haven't replied. What's happened to the other ELL mods? Anyway, Asim is currently abusing their privileges on the EL&U and physics site https://english.stackexchange.com/users/611858/asim-ahmed this is a recently deleted answer of  theirs.

Did I say Glorfindel is a moderator for six sites? Sorry,  I meant nine sites. No one should be a moderator for that many sites, and yes I know he's "Currently very busy with many real-life (work and private) projects;" but it's been two years.

@Mari-LouA Ah, I just saw my Spanish account. Where User Removed appeared twice. Do you think it was same guy? I just don't understand why they don't just ban the bum. :) His account was suspended UNTIL today. I just don't get it, do you?

@Lambie "User Removed" on Spanish SE was probably a coincidence, since I don't remember seeing any related accounts on Spanish. That message appears for both self deletions AND cases where a moderator deleted an account, so you probably won't get any more information about it.

Ah, I didn't know about the self-deletion one. When I think of the teeny, tiny vanilla things taken out of context on FSE that got me suspended, I wonder about OPs like this one who Mari-Lou found and is trying to get rid of. I don't understand why he is not booted. It just does not seem reasonable.

"I think I've handled everything here that needs to be handled" and I've been communicating with mods on other sites as this has spread, and was even able to get CMs involved, which will hopefully be the final word on this. Unfortunately, it's not over. The user has recently posted garbage on EL&U

I noticed that there are "only" four remaining accounts with the username "Asim Ahmed" today. Hooray! Thank you! Three of whom are suspended across the network while Asim Ahmed aka user:261344 (either undetected or mistranscribed by me because it is not listed) is not banned across the network. The other accounts seem to have been deleted. If you could update your answer and mention these developments I would be happy to accept the answer, and call it a day.

I forgot to add this user account, it has a different user name: user1128494 account number user:210172

@Mari-LouA Nine sites? Nine? That's a full-time job. That's why the Spanish site is not getting help from him.

@Lambie Escalated to Meta highlighting Spanish.SE issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405111/repeated-new-accounts

@Mari-LouA FYI, see comment above.

@NilayGhosh the user, asim ahmed–at least–never had an account on Spanish.SE So I don't think this is the same user. And having an Indian/Arab name would make it less likely that they are a speaker/learner of Spanish. By all means, link your comments on Meta to this page but this is not the place to mention every sock puppet that you come across.

@Lambie ELL didn't get any help from him either. He informed me he was on holiday.

@Mari-LouA Why does that not surprise me? :)

@Mari-LouA I am not talking about this specific user (Asim Ahmed) but the overall phenomenon and that it has been reported in Meta.SE. Hence informed here. Sockpuppets is a not a new thing but there has been surge in their activities network wide.
